# Navigation bar for a SPA using REACT.js

Tags: reactjs, uinavigationbar, single-page-application

I'm new to react, and I want to create a SPA.
 Now I have several components: Home, About, Team, Contact, and navigationbar. 
As I said, I want it to be SPA, for now, the sections are in different pages, How can I make them in one single page ?
 I have used Navbar, Navbar.Header, Nav,Navbar.Collapse, NavItem with "ComponentClass" "href" and to "attributes" for the navigationbar component , 
and Router and Route for the App Component. 
Anyone knows what I should do ?

Navigation bar code:

```
            <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <Link to="/">Scoot Smart Lock</Link>
                </Navbar.Brand>   
                <Navbar.Toggle/>
            </Navbar.Header> 
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav pullRight>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} ComponentClass={Link} href="/" to="/">
                        <span className="navItem">Home</span>
                    </NavItem> 
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} ComponentClass={Link} href="/about" to="/about">
                        <span className="navItem">About</span>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={3} ComponentClass={Link} href="/team" to="/team">
                        <span className="navItem">Team</span>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={4} ComponentClass={Link} href="/contact" to="/contact">
                        <span className="navItem">Contact</span>
                    </NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a Single Page Application or SPA?

Comment: Single Page Application

Comment: Please correct SAP to SPA then and also include some code of what you have tried so far.